# Different formatting for ordered lists in code tester and website

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a numbered list that goes like this:

10.1.1 test 
10.1.2 test 
10.1.3 test

...and so on. I've managed to achieve it with the following code and by testing with jsfiddler.net:

```
<ol class="list-10-1">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

With the following style

```
ol li{
        counter-increment: myIndex;
    }

    ol.list-10-1 li:before{
        content:"10.1."counter(myIndex)". ";
    }
```

However, when I've pasted the same html code in my Drupal website, I get

1. 10.1.1 test
2. 10.1.2 test
3. 10.1.3 test

Can someone please help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried searching for list-numbering? You're using generated content, you should have come across basic list-styling. If not, please search for `list-style-type`.

Comment: I've read about that. list-style-type doesn't offer style types of 10.1.#. Why the -1? I've already shown that I got it to work with a codetester like jsfiddler.net, just that it doesn't work on my website.

Comment: But setting it to `none` gets rid of the problem you describe.

Comment: You are right, and if I may repeat what I posted in the answer below, that solution creates another problem for me: the formatting of the next line [loses the left indent](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLce/5/) instead of [having a left indent](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLce/4/), and I'd like to be able to keep that formatting. I appreciate your help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
ol{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLce/2/)

Comment: Thanks!! That solved half of the problem, but the formatting of the next line [loses the left indent](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLce/5/) instead of [having a left indent](http://jsfiddle.net/9vLce/4/), and I'd like to be able to keep that formatting. May I know how can that be done? Thanks again!